# Import Excel Data to Datatable in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection

Is there any other way to import an Excel file data to a datatable and load it in Gridview in asp.net 2.0 using c#?

I tried using

```
OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+path+";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");
```

and it works in my local machine, but when i deployed it in network (server), it gives an error of

> The 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I know that I should install something to remove the error and make the web application work, but we are not allowed to install something in the server as it may affect other application integrated with it.

Any help please...

Comment: can u use linq instead of this oledb connection to read data?

Comment: installing OLEDB provider will not affect any other functionality on your server. As you will be using it in the application which you have created. There is no concern in installation, please explain your team about this and get it installed, otherwise you will need to read the data using SSIS if you have a SQL Server as your backend and fetch the records on ASP.NET page using a Store procedure.

Comment: I think the way to ago about working with office documents in .NET is Open XML

Answer (score 0):

First go through following msdn thread and try to resolve issue.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

If you do not want to install OLEDB provider on server, you should use .NET libraries to read/write Excel files. There are plenty of free libraries available like following. You can use one of these to populate collection or datatable to bind grid.

- [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com)
- NPOI
- Excel Package

You can download NPOI and Excel Package from CodePlex website